# Do While não está funcionando corretamente

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, do-while

Do while não está funcionando no código. A principio o teste que estou realizando agora é apenas o primeiro do menu (cadastra o usuário) e depois deveria voltar para o menu até ser digitado S. (Ele está executando somente uma unica vez) 
 Outra dúvida é como por o cadastrado em uma lista?

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class CadastraUsuarios {
 Scanner entrada;

    public void menu(){

    entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Clientes> listaDeUsuarios = new ArrayList<Clientes>();

    int op = 0,i,j;


    String opcao;
     do{
    System.out.println("MENU DE ESCOLHAS");
    System.out.println("A- CADASTRAR CLIENTE");
    System.out.println("B- INSERIR O CADASTRO DE UM NOVO TIPO ");
    System.out.println("C- LISTAR TODOS OS  CADASTRADOS");
    System.out.println("D- LISTAR TODOS OS CLIENTES CADASTRADOS");
    System.out.println("E- LISTAR OS  CADASTRADOS PARA UM DETERMINADO CLIENTE");
    System.out.println("F- BUSCAR INFORMAÇÕES DE UM PRODUTO PELO NÚMERO DE ");
    System.out.println("S- SAIR");

    opcao=entrada.nextLine().toUpperCase().trim();
    switch(opcao){
        case "A": System.out.println("Cadastro de Cliente:");


        System.out.println("Digite o nome do usuário");
        Clientes cliente = new Clientes(entrada.nextLine()); 
        System.out.println(cliente.getNome());

        //cadastrar clientes
        break;
        case "B": System.out.println("Inseririndo o cadastro de um novo tipo ...");
        //inserir o cadastro de um novo tipo de 
        break;
        case "C" : System.out.println("Listando todos os  cadastrados...");
        //listar todos os  cadastrados

        break;
        case "D" : System.out.println("Listando todos os clientes cadastrados...");
        //listar todos os clientes cadastrados

        break;
        case "E" : System.out.println("Listando os  cadastrados para um determinado cliente...");
        //listar os cadastrados para um determinado cliente

        break;
        case "F" : System.out.println("Buscando as informações   pelo número ...");
        //buscar as informações  pelo número 

        break;
        case "S" : System.out.println("saindo do programa...");
        //sair do programa

        break;



    }
}while(opcao=="S");

}

//String nome = scanner.nextLine(); cliente.setNome(nome);
}
```

Comment: Como nota adicional este código é um exemplo de como fazer o oposto da orientação a objeto.

Comment: @Maniero eu acho que é um exemplo de faculdade, quando estão ensinando entrada de dados no Java, é bem comum hoje em dia (e também era quando eu me formei).

Comment: @Maniero é um exemplo de faculdade, ainda não tenho muito afinidade com a programação orientada a objeto. Geralmente aparece um erro desse tipo. Me desculpe ehehehe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando se compara strings, deve-se utilizar o método `equals()`. Pois, os comparadores `==` irão comparar a referências dos objetos (se são o mesmo objeto).

O método `equals()` irá comparar se o valor de um objeto é o mesmo que o valor passado como parâmetro.

Logo, seria:

```
while(opcao.equals("S"));
```

Entretanto, eu imagino que o seu código deve repetir enquanto a opção "S" não for escolhida. Logo, sua comparação deve ser uma negação:

```
// enquanto não for "S", continue o loop
while(!opcao.equals("S"));
```

Mais informações:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java